# Error: Scope IdentityServerApi not found in store

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

While trying to add routing to additional endpoints within my project built with IdentityServer4, I ran into the following issue:

```
Error: Scope IdentityServerApi not found in store.
```

I followed [IdentityServer4's documentation for adding more API Endpoints](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html) exactly, so I wasn't sure why I was getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that in v4 IdentityServer is [moving away](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4415#:%7E:text=internal%20discussion%20around%20changing%20the%20language%20used%20surrounding%20the%20resources/scopes) from `ApiResources` and toward `ApiScopes`. For anyone just learning about IdentityServer4, it can be a little confusing navigating all of these changes, so hopefully this clarification will be helpful to someone else as well.

Solution: as opposed to what it says in the documentation included in my question, register your "LocalApi" as an `ApiScope` not an `ApiResource`. Following in an example of my setup for a local API:

Your config file:

```
// Add to your ApiScopes (not ApiResources)
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
   new ApiScope[]
   {
      new ApiScope(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)
   };

// Then add to your client's allowed scopes:
// ... extraneous code omitted ...
AllowedScopes = new string[]
{
   IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName
}
```

Your startup/program.cs:

```
// Register IdentityServer, then:
builder.Services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
```

Your "LocalApi" controller class:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that we're moving away from declaring the controllers as API Resources and then managing access to those via API Scopes?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with this, but yes I believe so